# Circle menu using jQuery and jQuery Radmenu Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, menu, geometry

http://goo.gl/zMiYs

Hello all, I managed to implement the menu above partially (menu opens, items appear, items move to destination) with the help of jQuery and jQuery Radmenu plugin. I used the following to make the targeted item rotate/move along the circle more than once because the way the radmenu is implemented, it moves items only once per click/event:

```
$('#radial_container').radmenu("next").radmenu("next");
```

However this is the point where I got stuck because I don't see the option to use a callback function once the animation stops (last `.radmenu("next")`). There is the plugin's "afterAnimation" option but it wasn't useful because it triggers after each `.radmenu("next")` - in other words too often. I also tried to work with jQuery's `queue()` and `dequeue()` but didn't have any luck.

I would highly appreciate it if I can get help on how to solve this problem or for pointing me in the right direction where I should look. In the last days, I spent a fair amount of time searching for similar menus but couldn't find anything similar to what I want to do considering it isn't an extremely exotic idea. Thanks!

*Edit:* Added link to menu explanation.

Comment: hey, could you provide an example you've worked on: js, html and/or put it on e.g. http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Yes of course, I should have thought about it when asking my question:

http://goo.gl/sBjS1

Comment: Are you asking how to rotate subsequent clicks to 3'o'clock, how to make the tooltip appear on hover, or what?

Comment: I'm not sure if you checked this: http://goo.gl/sBjS1 but the items move to the desired position after a single click. The problem is that I cannot trigger any callback function at all once the selected menu item is on 3 o'clock position. If I were to use a native jQuery animation like slideUp, I could do: $(this).click(function(){ $(this).slideUp(400, nextFunction) });
This would call the nextFunction after the animation has finished but its not the case using the radmenu plugin.

Comment: Also the way I move the different items to 3 o'clock is anything but elegant. Best would be to check the selected item's current Position (top and left) while it's beeing animated to the 3 o'clock position and once it's top and left values are the same like the top and left values of the 3 o'clock position, it would stop there and call another function to open the content etc.

I checked the top and left values of a selected item by using console.log($(this).position()); but I see only it's initial values. They don't get updated even the item has moved to a new position.

Answer (score 2):

My previous response was deleted, which upset me a little.

Never mind.

I think the solution you require might be something like this:

```
onSelect: function($selected){ // show what is returned 
  var i=0;
    while (i<= $selected.index())
    {
      jQuery("#radial_container").radmenu("next");
      i++;
    }
  },
```

Then just adjust your maths if required to make sure the destination is correct. If you want to be more clever, you can say that if the index is less than half way round the circle, choose prev instead of next.

I hope this helps you out. It's working fine for me.